# How to deal with Invalid Date in ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

I am currently writing a Rails application that uses a database that has been in use for a while. The PHP code that used to handle the db was able to use the datetime of '1999-00-00' for example. However, ActiveRecord seems to not let me use that date format.

What would be a way to handle such data without actually changing it in the database?

Is there a gem that helps with this that I haven't discovered yet?

EDIT: The answer is below. We changed the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Rails i18n to format and show the dates:

```
I18n.localize(Time.now) # using :default format
I18n.localize(Time.now, :format => :short) # using short format

I18n.localize(Date.today) # using :default format
I18n.localize(Date.today, :format => :short) # using short format
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want Jan 1, 1900, you could do:

```
>> your_field_before_type_cast = '1900-00-00'
=> "1900-00-00"
>> date = begin; Date.parse(your_field_before_type_cast); rescue ArgumentError; your_field_before_type_cast =~ /^(\d+)-/; Date.new($1.to_i, 1, 1); end
=> #<Date: 1900-01-01 ((2415021j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

so that would appear in your model as

```
def your_field
  Date.parse your_field_before_type_cast
rescue ArgumentError
  your_field_before_type_cast =~ /^(\d+)-/
  Date.new($1.to_i, 1, 1)
end
```

maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so the company decided to change the data in the database. Thanks for the suggestions guys.